# Increment / Decrement buttons only affect the first `<li>` instead of the selected one

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a shopping list where I can increment or decrement the quantity for each item with up and down buttons.
My issue is that when I click the buttons, instead of updating the quantity of the selected `<li>` element, only the input in the first `<li>` element is changed.

Here is my code at the moment:

```js
const listSelect = document.getElementById("liste")

function addItem() {
  const pdtValue = document.getElementById("pdt-input").value;
  const newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newLi.setAttribute('id', 'myLi');
  const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkbox.setAttribute("id", "check");
  checkbox.onclick = updateItem.bind(checkbox);
  const trash = document.createElement('button');
  trash.setAttribute("id", "delete");
  const icon = document.createElement('i');
  icon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-trash-alt');
  icon.setAttribute('style', 'pointer-events: none');
  const upButton = document.createElement('button');
  upButton.setAttribute('id', 'up');
  const upIcon = document.createElement('i');
  upIcon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-arrow-right');
  upIcon.setAttribute('style', 'pointer-events: none');
  const downButton = document.createElement('button');
  downButton.setAttribute('id', 'down');
  downButton.setAttribute('onClick', 'down()')
  const downIcon = document.createElement('i');
  downIcon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-arrow-left');
  downIcon.setAttribute('style', 'pointer-events: none');
  const Qty = document.createElement('input');
  Qty.setAttribute("type", "text");
  Qty.setAttribute("id", "quantity");
  Qty.setAttribute("value", "1");
  const text = document.createTextNode(pdtValue);


  if (pdtValue !== "") {
    newLi.appendChild(text);
    newLi.appendChild(downButton);
    downButton.appendChild(downIcon);
    newLi.appendChild(Qty);
    newLi.appendChild(upButton);
    upButton.appendChild(upIcon);
    newLi.appendChild(checkbox);
    newLi.appendChild(trash);
    trash.appendChild(icon);
    listSelect.appendChild(newLi)
  }

  newLi.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.id == "delete") {
      e.target.parentNode.remove();
    }
  });

  newLi.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.id == "up") {
      var quantité = document.getElementById('quantity');
      quantité.value++

    }
  });

  newLi.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.id == "down") {
      var quantité = document.getElementById('quantity');
      quantité.value--

    }
  });


  function updateItem() {
    if (this.checked) {
      this.parentNode.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    } else {
      this.parentNode.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-self: center;
  background-color: #faffba;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/beige-paper.png");
  min-height: 60px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 80vw;
}

button {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#check {
  margin-left: auto;
}

#addInputs {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

#quantity {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#up {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#down {
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Grocery List</h1>
  <ul id="liste">

  </ul>
  <div id="addInputs">
    <input placeholder="Produit" id="pdt-input"></input>
    <!--<input placeholder="Qty" id="qt-input"></input>-->
    <button class="add-btn" onClick="addItem()" value='Submit'>Add</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button onClick="customList()">
    Favs
  </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add relevant HTML and CSS to the snippet I made you

Comment: Never ever assign the same ID to multiple elements. ID **must be unique**. Try also to use characters without accents while naming your variables, stick to `a-zA-Z_$`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Do you have any support for the restrictive suggestion? (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1661197/438273)

Comment: @jsejcksn I'm well aware that you can use special characters. If it makes you happy, use emoticons in your variable names. But. Since a project can grow and reach multiple developers from around the world, we should stick to a widely available and limited characters set. And English. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Added the code from your "answer" right into your question

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Of course it does. The point I was making is that using French names is very accessible to French-reading/-writing developers, in the same way that using English names is not accessible to developers who aren’t strong in English. It’s just about who’s maintaining the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a same ID `quantité` for all created input elements:

```
Qty.setAttribute("id", "quantité");
```

So when you target the element by ID , the script will select the first element matching that ID. You may use ordered id like `quantité1` and `quantité2` etc. or preferably using another logic for selector which refers to the nearest input maybe something like this:

```
var quantité = this.querySelector("#quantité");
```

or

```
var quantité = this.querySelector("input");
```

Comment: Using IDs is redundant anyways, and your suggestion of keeping track of *numbered IDs* can only complicate in a GUI where items are added and deleted. There's no need to use IDs at all.

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in comments. Don't use duplicated IDs.
Actually, **don't use IDs at all.**

Here's a nice example which will also spare you the code madness you currently use:

```js
// Helper functions:

const EL = (sel, el) => (el||document).querySelector(sel); 
const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);


// Component: PDT

const pdt_new = (data) => {
    
  const EL_li  = ELNew("li", { className: "pdt-item" });
  const EL_txt = ELNew("span", { textContent: data.text });
  const EL_qty = ELNew("input", { type: "text", value: data.value});
    
  const decrement = () => EL_qty.value = Math.max(1, +EL_qty.value - 1);
  const increment = () => EL_qty.value = +EL_qty.value + 1
  const update    = () => EL_li.classList.toggle("line-through", EL_chk.checked);
  const remove    = () => EL_li.remove();
    
  const EL_chk = ELNew("input",  { type: "checkbox", onclick: update});
  const EL_dec = ELNew("button", { type: "button", onclick: decrement, innerHTML: `<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>`});
  const EL_inc = ELNew("button", { type: "button", onclick: increment, innerHTML: `<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>`});
  const EL_del = ELNew("button", { type: "button", onclick: remove, innerHTML: `<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>`});
    
  EL_li.append(EL_txt, EL_qty, EL_dec, EL_inc, EL_chk, EL_del);
  EL("#pdt-list").append(EL_li);
};

const pdt_add = () => {
  const text = EL("#pdt-input").value;  // Get item name
  if (!text) return;          // No value, do nothing
  pdt_new({text: text, value: 1}); // Create new list item
};

EL("#pdt-add").addEventListener("click", pdt_add);


// Example: prepopulate from existing data:

[
    {text: "Lorem", value: 9},
    {text: "Ipsum", value: 2},
].forEach(pdt_new);
```

```css
#pdt-list {
  padding: 0;
}

.pdt-item {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.pdt-item.line-through {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.pdt-item span {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul id="pdt-list"></ul>
<input id="pdt-input" type="text"><button id="pdt-add">Add</button>
```